# How to make H2O driverless AI use more cores on CPU?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, h2o, multicore, driverless-ai

My machine has 20 cores on its CPU, but when running Driverless AI, it uses only 4 of them.How can I make it use more cores for faster results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend on your setup and what version of DAI you are using, but you can specify the number of CPUs you want to use in the `config.toml` file. For your convenience I have pasted the relevant section of the toml file below as well as provided the documentation link that includes details for setting up this file.

```
## Hardware: Configure hardware settings here (GPUs, CPUs, Memory, etc.)

# Max number of CPU cores to use per experiment. Set to <= 0 to use all cores.
# One can also set environment variable "OMP_NUM_THREADS" to number of cores to use for OpenMP
# e.g. In bash: export OMP_NUM_THREADS=32 and export OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=32
#Set to -1 for all available cores.
#max_cores = -1
```

documentation [link](http://docs.h2o.ai/driverless-ai/latest-stable/docs/userguide/config_toml.html?highlight=cpu#using-the-config-toml-file)